# how can i put a default image in my table for every user?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am using PHP with MYSQL and want to add a feature to upload profile image. I want to display a default image if the user has not uploaded his imageyet. I have declared the profile image field of database as BLOB. I am getting no option in that case to put a default image directly through database. Please help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle it in your code. No need to copy the same image into every user's database field.

```
if (!$user['image']) {
    // output default image
} else {
    // output $user['image']
}
```

In fact, you should store images outside the database to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing the same blob image potentially many thousands/millions of times, have your PHP code do a little check - if the field is empty, point it to a file on the filesystem somewhere that is used for them. If there is data in there *then* use the image that is in the user's row of data.

On that note, you actually [CANNOT assign a default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) value to a blob.

You *can* however do this: Create a second table in the database and insert the blob into it. Then create an `on insert` trigger on the table you are using, and after the insert is done, use something like this:

```
UPDATE BLOB_table SET BLOB_field = (select defaultBlob from othertableName);
```

But having said that, wasting potentially millions of rows of blobs should cause you to cringe. Have your PHP code check and assign a default if you don't find a blob in the row.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar feature in my application. If there's no image uploaded, I return a redirect to a default image:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0) {
  header("Location: $default_image_url");
} else {
  // Code to output image
}
```